# refer a captured group without case sensitivity

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, repeat

I define "Repeating words" as this regex (use PyPI package, not builtin `re`):

```
import regex
repeating = regex.compile(r"(\w+)(?:\W+\1){4,}")
```

It will catch words that are repeated 5 times or more, for example

> Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer

However, if the word varies by capitalization, the regex fails:

> Answer answer Answer answer Answer answer Answer answer Answer answer

How can I modify the regex so it catches "repeating words" that varies in capitalization? I want it to match

> answer ANSWER ansWER Answer anSwer AnSwEr

Note: `str.lower()` is not an option because I need the exact capitalization of the captured group.

Comment: Is there some case insensitive flag you can use?

Comment: Just write (?i) in the beginning of regex

Comment: You can also use `regex.IGNORECASE` flag

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It changes how the regex matches, but captured groups are still referred verbatim

Comment: @iBug What do you mean, it changes how the regex matches? If you want backreferences to work with different capitalization, you have to use case-insensitive.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I mean, with `(?i)`, `aaa` can match `aaA`, but `(a)\1+` doesn't match `aaA` because `\1` refers to `a` not `A`.

Comment: Sure it does match `aaA` https://regex101.com/r/3uwKrM/1

Comment: Um.. Why using flag is not considered at all? RAN has pointed it out.

Comment: @Sraw using flag will consider `answer` and `Answer` as same match and only one will appear in result, whereas op want both of them in result since they are in different case.

Comment: `repeating = regex.compile(r"(\w+)(?:\W+\1){4,}", regex.I)`, then `print(repeating.search("answer ANSWER ansWER Answer anSwer AnSwEr").group())` prints `answer ANSWER ansWER Answer anSwer AnSwEr`.